# Pass URL in request

Tags: node.js, express

My app restricts users to access certain functionalities and redirects to a login page if not logged in. I want to save the URL that was requested before the login page. How can I do so?
I have tried using locals:

```
function restrict(req, res, next) {

if (!req.session.userName){
    res.locals['url'] = req.originaUrl;

    res.redirect('/login');
}
else
    next();
}


app.get('/login', require('./src/controllers/pages/loginPageController'))
```

How can I access locals in my login controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not a node.js person but you can usually choose one of:

1. Use the `session` to store the URL that the user visited
2. When you redirect add the vistited URL as parameter ie: `login?landPath=/path/the/user/went/to/first/time`

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

you can use sessions

req.session

```
var users = require('./src/controllers/pages/loginPageController');
var session = require('client-sessions');
function requireLogIn(req,res,next){
  if(req.session.user)
    next();
  else if(!req.session.user) {
    res.redirect('/loginPage');
  }
}
// for storing sessions
app.use(session({
  cookieName: 'session',
  secret: 'this-is-my-unencrypted-key-it-will-be-encrypted-by-client-sessions-    package',
  duration: 60 * 60 * 1000,
  activeDuration: 30 * 60 * 1000,
}));
app.use('/users', requireLogIn, users);
```